# Парсинг сайта ip адрессов с веб страниц python

Tags: python, синтаксический-анализ

Стоит задача пройтись по ссылкам сайта

http://www.zone-h.org/archive

открывать ссылки вида
http://www.zone-h.org/mirror/id/22714269

и копировать поле с IP адрессом в единый текстовый файл.

Как посоветуете реализовать на Питоне? Какие посоветуете библиотеки/примеры использовать?
Спасибо за советы.

Comment: Чем родной питоновский html.parser не устроил?

Comment: Эмъ... это только для меня для получения IP надо было капчу вводить? Или вы на питоне хотите это обойти?

Т.е. вы предлагаете нам помочь вам  написать робот, который легко может быть превращен в спам-робот?

UPD: открыл повторно - уже без капчи, открыл в "режиме инкогнито" - без капчи. А первый раз - с капчей было. Странно все это )

Comment: У меня никаких каптч не спрашивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С содержимым сайта очень удобно работать используя [Grab](http://docs.grablib.org/), а Browser из [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) позволяет почувствовать себя настоящим браузером :) кстати, grab тоже умеет обрабатывать редиректы, куки, выбирать случайный юзерагент из своего списка или пользовательского, а также прокси и все необходимое...

[Эта статья](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-python-mechanize-beautiful-soup/) мне когда-то очень помогла - позволяет быстро вникнуть в то, как нужно парсить, что для этого использовать (стоит взглянуть на дату публикации) и все в этом духе.